Why use std::swap instead of std::move for (optional) out values?
I am looking at code from Microsoft and I noticed the following:
An optional parameter std::vector<T>* vOut is passed into a function.
The function itself uses a separate local std::vector<T> result for the optional result.
At the end of the function, they do the following to pass the result to the caller:
if(vOut) {
    std::swap(*vOut,result);
}

why would someone use a std::swap here instead of a move-assignment like
*vOut = std::move(result)?
Here is an example

As a nit I would actually use member swap instead vOut->swap(result)

Looks like six of one, versus half-dozen of the other.  Is there any advantage to either one?  Doesn't appear to be to me.  Either ought to be as good as the other.  Unless you've profiled the two ways of implementing it, and discovered that one way is superior to the other.

@Eljay no one here said anything about performance. however a std::move would actually signal ownership transfer, wouldn't it?

@Raildex that commit is from 10 years ago, and there is a good chance the code is even older. So, it's very much possible that std::move wasn't available/supported then.

A std::swap signals ownership exchange, and does not have the potential use-after-move problem that std::move has.  (Not that use-after-move is a problem in this case.  Nor is performance a problem in this case.)

@CoryKramer you shouldn't. See Swappable

Well, there is always the possibility that something was made pre-C++11, so moves might not have been available.
However, I might occasionally use swap when I want the other object to be in a "better defined" state -- that is, move the data but also have a clear object, instead of just one that's merely safe to use.
And, last but not least, somebody might not think about every tiny detail -- not every piece of production code is meant as a textbook example, and std::move vs. std::swap, in many cases, is micro-optimization at best (the move might even be implemented on top of a swap member), so it's not something to be particularly concerned about.

Even if the code wasn't written pre-C++11, a lot of programmers will have gotten into the habit of using std::swap in this case, and since it doesn't make a difference, they'll probably not bother changing their habits.

@JamesKanze yeah, that's kind of what I tried to cover with the third option :-)
